# Are polynomials infinitely many times differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Are polynomials infinitely many times differentiable?

If so, does it only mean that at some point we reach 0 and then we keep on getting 0?

Thank you!

Comment: That is exactly correct. Good thinking!

Comment: Yes, polynomials are infinitely many times differentiable, and yes, after some finite number of derivatives (specifically $\deg f + 1$) we get $0$, and then we continue to get $0$ thereafter.

Comment: ... but that's not what it **means**, it's just what happens in this case when you keep differentiating.

Comment: For example, $\sin x$ is infinitely differentiable, but you never reach and stay at zero.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

$$\frac{d}{dx} 0 = 0,$$
so once you've taken $\deg(p) + 1$ derivatives, where $p$ is the polynomial you're considering, you will just keep getting zero.

Comment: If in this logic, then constant function is also infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Yes --- the constant functions are just a special case of this, being the degree zero polynomials.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers probably answered your question, but in case you wanted to learn more, the key word to look up is smoothness of the function (see here for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).

So another, more fancy way of asking your question is whether or not polynomials are smooth functions.

Comment: Only one of the two other answers is _above_. You may want to change your wording to make it more independent of surroundings.

Comment: Changed the wording. Thanks!