# if $f(x)$ is a polynomial with complex coefficients, what does $|f(x)|\geq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$ imply?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I understand that this means f has no roots and the polynomial is of degree zero. But why is that the case and how do we know that being greater than equal to 1 means f(x) has no roots?

also, are there any ways to analyse this apart from Liouville's Theorem (as I am not very acquainted with that)?

Comment: If $x$ is a root then $|f(x)|=0 <1$

Comment: Since $1/f$ is a bounded entire function, it must be constant by [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: All polynomials of any degree greater than zero have at least one root in $\mathbb C$. This is the fundamental theorem of algebra. No roots means the degree must be less than 1..

Comment: It looks like you are having a [complex (analysis) day](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105647/if-fx-is-a-polynomial-with-complex-coefficients-prove-that-if-fx-leq-1)? :)

Comment: @rtybase yep! struggling with the concept :(

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of algebra, it means that the polynomial in question is a constant located outside the disk around $0$ Of radius one.

Comment: Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Proofs

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, what you need here is the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra&oldid=1044392015), which says that every nonconstant polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

So, suppose that $f$ is a polynomial that satisfies $\lvert f(z) \rvert \geq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is nonconstant, then by the fundamental theorem of algebra there is a point $z_0$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$. But then $\lvert f(z_0) \rvert = 0 < 1$, which is a contradiction. Hence, any such $f$ must be a constant polynomial. (Indeed, if $a$ is any complex number such that $\lvert a \rvert \geq 1$, then the constant polynomial $f(z) = a$ satisfies the given condition.)